# Angular Error: Module 'crmMailing' is not available! When CiviMail is enabled

Tags: civimail, angular

We are running a Bitnami Stack for CiviCrm and Drupal on our own local VM server.

https://bitnami.com/stack/civicrm

Our versions are

- CiviCrm 4.7.13
- Drupal 7.52

I grant access to CiviCrm features using admin/people/permissions in Drupal. If I enable "CiviMail: access CiviMail" for the administrator, and then attempt to view one of these two pages as an administrator:

- /civicrm/a/#/status
- /civicrm/a/#/caseType

I get a blank page under "CiviCRM System Status" and "CaseTypes" respectively.

Using Chrome to debug the page, I find an exception: Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr]

You can drill down using the link below, but it would appear that crmMailing module is a dependency of the crmApp module, and crmMailing is not available.

I believe I have something configured wrong. Or is this a known issue?  I can work around this by simply removing the administrator's permission to see 'CiviMail: access CiviMail'. But if I have this set up wrong then I am wondering what else I am missing.

We are new to CiviCRM and Drupal. But I believe this is the tool we have been looking for for our organization.

Here's the link to the angular error:

> Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr]
>
> https: //docs.angularjs.org/error/$injector/modulerr?p0=crmApp&p1=Error:%20%5B$injector:modulerr%5D%20http:%2F%2Ferrors.angularjs.org%2F1.3.20%2F$injector%2Fmodulerr%3Fp0%3DcrmMailing%26p1%3DError%253A%2520%255B%2524injector%253Anomod%255D%2520http%253A%252F%252Ferrors.angularjs.org%252F1.3.20%252F%2524injector%252Fnomod%253Fp0%253DcrmMailing%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520at%2520http%253A%252F%252Fintranet.morningstarcc.org%252Fsites%252Fall%252Fmodules%252Fcivicrm%252Fbower_components%252Fangular%252Fangular.min.js%252Cqolsedh.pagespeed.jm.mJ6DmSqj5A.js%253A1%253A417%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520at%2520http%253A%252F%252Fintranet.morningstarcc.org%252Fsites%252Fall%252Fmodules%252Fcivicrm%252Fbower_components%252Fangular%252Fangular.min.js%252Cqolsedh.pagespeed.jm.mJ6DmSqj5A.js%253A5%253A412%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520at%2520a%2520(http%253A%252F%252Fintranet.morningstarcc.org%252Fsites%252Fall%252Fmodules%252Fcivicrm%252Fbower_components%252Fangular%252Fangular.min.js%252Cqolsedh.pagespeed.jm.mJ6DmSqj5A.js%253A5%253A53)%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520at%2520http%253A%252F%252Fintranet.morningstarcc.org%252Fsites%252Fall%252Fmodules%252Fcivicrm%252Fbower_components%252Fangular%252Fangular.min.js%252Cqolsedh.pagespeed.jm.mJ6DmSqj5A.js%253A5%253A296%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520at%2520http%253A%252F%252Fintranet.morningstarcc.org%252Fsites%252Fall%252Fmodules%252Fcivicrm%252Fbower_components%252Fangular%252Fangular.min.js%252Cqolsedh.pagespeed.jm.mJ6DmSqj5A.js%253A5%253A7186%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520at%2520r%2520(http%253A%252F%252Fintranet.morningstarcc.org%252Fsites%252Fall%252Fmodules%252Fcivicrm%252Fbower_components%252Fangular%252Fangular.min.js%252Cqolsedh.pagespeed.jm.mJ6DmSqj5A.js%253A1%253A827)%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520at%2520g%2520(http%253A%252F%252Fintranet.morningstarcc.org%252Fsites%252Fall%252Fmodules%252Fcivicrm%252Fbower_components%252Fangular%252Fangular.min.js%252Cqolsedh.pagespeed.jm.mJ6DmSqj5A.js%253A5%253A7034)%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520at%2520http%253A%252F%252Fintranet.morningstarcc.org%252Fsites%252Fall%252Fmodules%252Fcivicrm%252Fbower_components%252Fangular%252Fangular.min.js%252Cqolsedh.pagespeed.jm.mJ6DmSqj5A.js%253A5%253A7203%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520at%2520r%2520(http%253A%252F%252Fintranet.morningstarcc.org%252Fsites%252Fall%252Fmodules%252Fcivicrm%252Fbower_components%252Fangular%252Fangular.min.js%252Cqolsedh.pagespeed.jm.mJ6DmSqj5A.js%253A1%253A827)%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520at%2520g%2520(http%253A%252F%252Fintranet.morningstarcc.org%252Fsites%252Fall%252Fmodules%252Fcivicrm%252Fbower_components%252Fangular%252Fangular.min.js%252Cqolsedh.pagespeed.jm.mJ6DmSqj5A.js%253A5%253A7034)%0A%20%20%20%20at%20http:%2F%2Fintranet.morningstarcc.org%2Fsites%2Fall%2Fmodules%2Fcivicrm%2Fbower_components%2Fangular%2Fangular.min.js,qolsedh.pagespeed.jm.mJ6DmSqj5A.js:1:417%0A%20%20%20%20at%20http:%2F%2Fintranet.morningstarcc.org%2Fsites%2Fall%2Fmodules%2Fcivicrm%2Fbower_components%2Fangular%2Fangular.min.js,qolsedh.pagespeed.jm.mJ6DmSqj5A.js:5:7460%0A%20%20%20%20at%20r%20(http:%2F%2Fintranet.morningstarcc.org%2Fsites%2Fall%2Fmodules%2Fcivicrm%2Fbower_components%2Fangular%2Fangular.min.js,qolsedh.pagespeed.jm.mJ6DmSqj5A.js:1:827)%0A%20%20%20%20at%20g%20(http:%2F%2Fintranet.morningstarcc.org%2Fsites%2Fall%2Fmodules%2Fcivicrm%2Fbower_components%2Fangular%2Fangular.min.js,qolsedh.pagespeed.jm.mJ6DmSqj5A.js:5:7034)%0A%20%20%20%20at%20http:%2F%2Fintranet.morningstarcc.org%2Fsites%2Fall%2Fmodules%2Fcivicrm%2Fbower_components%2Fangular%2Fangular.min.js,qolsedh.pagespeed.jm.mJ6DmSqj5A.js:5:7203%0A%20%20%20%20at%20r%20(http:%2F%2Fintranet.morningstarcc.org%2Fsites%2Fall%2Fmodules%2Fcivicrm%2Fbower_components%2Fangular%2Fangular.min.js,qolsedh.pagespeed.jm.mJ6DmSqj5A.js:1:827)%0A%20%20%20%20at%20g%20(http:%2F%2Fintranet.morningstarcc.org%2Fsites%2Fall%2Fmodules%2Fcivicrm%2Fbower_components%2Fangular%2Fangular.min.js,qolsedh.pagespeed.jm.mJ6DmSqj5A.js:5:7034)%0A%20%20%20%20at%20cb%20(http:%2F%2Fintranet.morningstarcc.org%2Fsites%2Fall%2Fmodules%2Fcivicrm%2Fbower_components%2Fangular%2Fangular.min.js,qolsedh.pagespeed.jm.mJ6DmSqj5A.js:5:8831)%0A%20%20%20%20at%20d%20(http:%2F%2Fintranet.morningstarcc.org%2Fsites%2Fall%2Fmodules%2Fcivicrm%2Fbower_components%2Fangular%2Fangular.min.js,qolsedh.pagespeed.jm.mJ6DmSqj5A.js:3:1431)%0A%20%20%20%20at%20tc%20(http:%2F%2Fintranet.morningstarcc.org%2Fsites%2Fall%2Fmodules%2Fcivicrm%2Fbower_components%2Fangular%2Fangular.min.js,qolsedh.pagespeed.jm.mJ6DmSqj5A.js:3:1744

Comment: Hi Rod, were you able to fix the issue? If yes let me know what fixed it?